# Killing vector field on the Poincaré upper half-plane

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I need to define a **Killing vector field** $W$ on the *Poincaré upper half-plane* model, $\mathbb{R} = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2| y > 0 \}$ with the metric $g=\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}$, s.t. $$||W||<1$$ and the flow $\varphi(t,(x,y))$ of $W$ in not difficult to find. Actually I want to work with the flow of such a vector field. Whatever I construct is not Killing or it does not satisfies the condition of norm less than 1.

Any idea?

Comment: Any nonzero Killing vector field on the Poincaré upper half-plane has unbounded norm, so I'm afraid that you are asking for something that doesn't exist.  (I'm assuming that your norm is the natural norm induced by the Poincaré metric itself.)

Comment: @RobertBryant Yes the norm is what you considered. I did not know about the norm of a Killing field on the upper half-plane. Super thanks!